# How do I find out my iMac display panel's manufacturer?

Tags: display, imac

I've had problems with image retention on my late-2012 27" iMac for a few months now and Apple's ["avoiding image retention" support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202580) is useless for me.

On MacBooks, one can use [this Terminal one-liner](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4990702?tstart=0) to check one's display manufacturer. Is there a similar command for iMacs? I realize that I'll have to return my iMac sooner or later because this is unacceptable, but I'd still like to know what panel I have before I do it.

Comment: Did that Terminal command not work when you tried it on your iMac?

Comment: It did not. It just returned an empty string.

Comment: Weird. If it works for MacBooks, I would assume it would work for iMacs. What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: 10.11.3. Apparently, this just doesn't work with non-portable Macs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an LG LM270WQ1 (SD)(F1).

One thread is here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5591164?tstart=0
And you can find replacement here: [http://www.amazon.com/Apple-A1419-Screen-LM270WQ1-661-7169/dp/B00LEXN39W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LEXN39W)

Comment: Is it always an LG panel though? Getting a "repaired" iMac with another crappy LG panel would really suck.

Comment: @PeterW. LG has made the displays for Apple stuff for AT LEAST 15 years; I know this because when repairing an old PowerBook G4 I noticed that the display was branded LG.